# Qt program fails to compile/has runtime error (IDE: CodeBlocks/QtCreator)

Tags: c++, qt, codeblocks

I am new to Qt. While I have installed 4.8.3 for long, I started writing my first Qt program yesterday. I am under windows environment, and use CodeBlocks for my C++ codes.

I followed the book on Qt programming, and tried to reproduce the book examples. Problem arose in the second chapter, when there was a need of separate compilation. I never had a successful separate compilation with CodeBlocks, and no exception this time: I still received "unknown reference to XXX".

I tried to find all instructions online but I still could not solve it (set up qmake, linking etc.) Especially when I used qmake and mark the makefile as custom one, whenever I compiled my program, CodeBlocks told me that the project hadnt been built; when I clicked "yes" for building the program, the same "hasnt been built" notification popped out, and the process repeated.

I once suspected that something went wrong with my Qt, so I removed it and installed the latest one (which is Qt5.0). But I could not use it because CodeBlocks only supports Qt4, and my compiler does not support Qt5.

So I tried to download the "old one", 4.8.4. Then it turned out that I could not even compile a one-file program (I mean one .cpp file in the whole project, no self-defined header). I tried the default CodeBlock qt program, which is like this:

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QFont>
    #include <QPushButton>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        QPushButton quit("Quit");
        quit.resize(75, 30);
        quit.setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));
        QObject::connect(&quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
        quit.show();
        return app.exec();
    }
```

Just a very standard one. It should compile, and it did, but things were even worse: the program never works, as runtime error occurs right after it is executed (error code: 0xC0000005 or -1073741819)
This is my problem 1: I have no clues, what can I do to solve the problem? I do not mind deleting my CodeBlocks and Qt and doing the reinstallation if they work, but I have tried, and no use.

My second problem: (this is solved)
Then I tried to use Qt Creator. When I compiled the simple program shown above, I received a lot of errors with keywords "unwind_resume" - can anyone tell me how I can solve it? (Online comments suggest running qtvar.bat, but it didnt help; some suggested building debug library, which I tried but accidentally stopped because of not enough memory?)

My third problem: (found it rather redundant because it is discussed above, so I have deleted it)

(I should say thanks first to people who really read my post. And I have to say that while information provided may not be sufficient for finding solution, this is all I know.)

Update - Some more info: actually I also had similar undefined reference for CodeBlocks. But I was lazy and so I just copied all the .dll files from the qt folder to the SysWOW64; programs did compile and run yesterday, but programs crashed with runtime error after I reinstalled qt and codeblocks today, even though I also copied the new .dll files. To make things clear: Codeblocks can compile the program if I copy the .dll files to SysWOW64, but now the program crashes, unlike yesterday as the program ran normally.)

Update - now the problem is runtime error.

Comment: call stack? have you tried to debug it?

Comment: There's a way to tell if CodeBlocks is faulty: compile the program from the terminal. I faced a similar problem once (with QtCreator) and compiled the code by hand. It went well, it was a cache problem. Try this: `qmake -project` followed by `qmake` and `make`. Then launch the binary and see if everything goes as expected. I tried yout code in Windows with MingW and worked.

Comment: unwind_resume is usually because of a faulty codeblocks install or project, usually the project is to blame.

Comment: @Need4Sleep I encountered unwind_resume in QtCreator but not CodeBlocks actually.

Comment: @AdriC.S. Forgive me if you find this stupid: I know how to use terminal in linux, but do not know how to use cmd in windows. Actually how can I run qmake in cmd if my cpp file is in another folder?

Comment: @DickWong don't worry :). I don't know exactly how to tell that from the cmd, but you can do this: create the project with `qmake -project`. Then edit the `.pro` file and specify the source file with `SOURCES += <PATH_TO_FILE>/main.cpp`. For example: `SOURCES += "C:\Test\sources\main.cpp`. That should work.

Comment: Another thing. I'm supposing that you have updated the Windows `PATH` (your user path would suffice) with the path to `qmake.exe`.

Comment: Ok, more things. You can specify the files this way: `qmake.exe -project <PATH_TO_FILES>`. Example: `qmake.exe -project headers/*.h sources/*.cpp`. This way you're telling `qmake` to create a project with all the `.h` and `.cpp` files in those folders.

Comment: @AdriC.S. Tried the command line compilation. Current problem is unwind_resume and undefined reference to __gxx__personality_v0 (not yet the runtime error).
For the PATH thing I just added " C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin" in PATH; do I need to create new environment variables like INCLUDE and LIB?

Comment: The PATH is fine. The cmd should recognize the `qmake.exe`. So, are you able to compile the project from the cmd? As @Need4Sleep said, the `unwind_resume` is probably CodeBlocks fault. Also, that's the common thing said when I googled `unwind_resume c++`.

Comment: I can't. The cmd also displays `unwind_resume` in the process.
It is not really CodeBlock specific stuff, because not only does this happen in cmd now, it also appeared when I tried QtCreator earlier.
(And the biggest thing is in fact the runtime error, but let's just solve `unwind_resume` first)

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://sandundhammika.wordpress.com/tag/_unwind_resume/)? But its not a solution, but might give us a clear view of another problem, that is causing all this.

Comment: Well, try removing all files from the directory where you're calling `qmake.exe`. Leave only those indispensable, i.e: sources, `.pro`, etc. Then call `qmka.exe -project ...` and `qmake` and `make` again. Also, maybe this post helps (if you hadn't read it already): [link](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/33394-Link-errors-undefined-reference-to-_Unwind_Resume-and-__gxx_personality_v0). If this doesn't help, I'm out of ideas, sorry :(

Comment: @dowhilefor this is interesting, I will try it. I know the new problem (ignoring exceptions etc) is terrible.

Comment: @AdriC.S. I can compile the program now. Thanks for your steps so far.
And it is time to discuss the next issue: runtime error. The executable obtained afterwards crashed as soon as it was run. No clues at all.

Comment: (A follow up question: let me put the runtime error aside. I can compile the program in CodeBlocks, but can run only if I copy all the .dll files from the \bin to SysWOW64 manually, otherwise there will be "Entry Point Not Found" and "...could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll" (there wont be "Entry Point Not Found" error when the .dll files are available, but we will have to face runtime error) . I think this is not appropriate, and I wonder if I should do something instead of copying the dll files.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's recap here and stop concatenating comment after comment.

For your first question, we cleared the building folder of any previous compilation, leaving only the needed files, i.e: `.cpp` files, `.h/hpp` files and the `.pro` file (along with any resource file you might need, which is not the case for this example).

Then compiling *by hand* from the terminal/cmd you could build the project:

```
qmake.exe -project <PATH_TO_NEEDED_FILES>
qmake
make
```

Now, for your second question of the runtime error and the `Entry Point Not Found`...
Well, I'm clueless. Googleing a bit I found that the most common cause for the `Entry Point` error is that the `Qt` is linking against an old version dll:

[Entry Point Error 1](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17171)

[Entry Point Error 2](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15810-Procedure-entry-point-not-located)

[Entry Point Error 3](http://www.qtforum.org/article/20931/entry-point-not-found.html)

In the second link, the problem was resolved by setting the Qt path as first one in the Windows `PATH`. Maybe that helps.

Let's hope that anyone with more experience helps!!

Comment: I will try... the `Entry Point` error is really annoying. I'm using 4.8.4 dlls but it is not quite satisfactory. Anyway I assume I cannot find a nice way to solve it in the end, and perhaps copying the dll files to SysWOW64 is the only option.

Comment: Hi. In my PC I haven't set any vars. I just have the path to Qt bin folder in the Windows system path. However, I can't tell for sure that there are no links or whatsoever around, since when I started work, Qt was already installed waiting for me. Right now I'm clueless. If I come up with something, I'll let you know. Bye!

Comment: One last question on runtime:
When I try to remove my codes line by line in the program, I discover that the runtime error starts from the very beginning: `   QApplication app(argc, argv);` in other words I cannot write any Qt program. How can I catch exception so that I can find some more clues? I try using the standard `try` and `catch (exception e) cout<<e.what();` but the program just crashed without exception and I cannot guess what happened

Comment: Well, that's strange. That's the line that must be place before any other Qt calls for the app to work. Maybe a linkage problem?

Comment: It seems that the only exceptions available in Qt are those in the `QConcurrent` module. If you haven't done it yet, I think it would be better to ask directly in the Qt forums. The developers may know what's happening.